# Проблема с корректным расположением файла при сборке Maven

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, spring, maven

У меня есть проект на `Spring Boot` и у меня вопрос по поводу путей до `View`

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/front/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/ui/").setViewName("forward:/ui/index.html");
        registry.addViewController("/ui").setViewName("forward:/ui/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    }
}
```

Здесь есть метод `addViewControllers`, который, как я понимаю, делает сопоставление урла `/ui` и `/ui/` с `index.html`, но есть некоторая проблема: где должна находиться страница `index.html`? Просто самой страницы `index.html` не существует в папке `resources` в `Spring` приложении, так как она относится к `React` и присутствует только при сборке `.jar` файла. Можете подсказать куда именно в `.jar` файле нужно помещать эту страницу, чтобы при обращении к `localhost:8080/ui/` у меня эта страница корректно отображалась? На данный момент в папке `target` нечто такое (`index.html` как раз таки располагается в `target/classes/static/ui/`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что находило `index.html` по пути `/ui/index.html` из `target/classes/static/ui` нужно задать конфигурацию:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/ui/");
```

Все что в `target/classes` попадает в корень собранного jar-a, а все содержимое `jar`-a, находится в `classpath`.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало)